# Unable to compile the java project even after the jar file has been added?

Tags: java, eclipse, jms

I have been working on building the project using the jms service. I have created the project in eclipse.

```
Project name : JmsTest
src->jmstestclient(package)->SimpleProducer.java(class)
```

The code for SimpleProducer.java is as follows

```
import javax.jms.*;
import javax.naming.*;


public class SimpleSynchConsumer {
    /**
     * Main method.
     *
     * @param args     the destination name and type used by the
     *                 example
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String destName = null;
        Context jndiContext = null;
        ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = null;
        Connection connection = null;
        Session session = null;
        Destination dest = null;
        MessageConsumer consumer = null;
        TextMessage message = null;

        if (args.length != 1) {
            System.out.println("Program takes one argument: <dest_name>");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        destName = new String(args[0]);
        System.out.println("Destination name is " + destName);

        /*
         * Create a JNDI API InitialContext object if none exists
         * yet.
         */
        try {
            jndiContext = new InitialContext();
        } catch (NamingException e) {
            System.out.println("Could not create JNDI API context: " +
                e.toString());
            System.exit(1);
        }

        /*
         * Look up connection factory and destination.  If either
         * does not exist, exit.  If you look up a
         * TopicConnectionFactory or a QueueConnectionFactory,
         * program behavior is the same.
         */
        try {
            connectionFactory = (ConnectionFactory) jndiContext.lookup(
                    "jms/ConnectionFactory");
            dest = (Destination) jndiContext.lookup(destName);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("JNDI API lookup failed: " + e.toString());
            System.exit(1);
        }

        /*
         * Create connection.
         * Create session from connection; false means session is
         * not transacted.
         * Create consumer, then start message delivery.
         * Receive all text messages from destination until
         * a non-text message is received indicating end of
         * message stream.
         * Close connection.
         */
        try {
            connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
            session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
            consumer = session.createConsumer(dest);
            connection.start();

            while (true) {
                Message m = consumer.receive(1);

                if (m != null) {
                    if (m instanceof TextMessage) {
                        message = (TextMessage) m;
                        System.out.println("Reading message: " +
                            message.getText());
                    } else {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (JMSException e) {
            System.out.println("Exception occurred: " + e.toString());
        } finally {
            if (connection != null) {
                try {
                    connection.close();
                } catch (JMSException e) {
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have downloaded the javax.jms-3.1.2.2 jar file and placed this file inside bin\lib under the java folder. But i am getting the following error.

```
The import javax.jms cannot be resolved. 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    ConnectionFactory cannot be resolved to a type
    Connection cannot be resolved to a type
    Session cannot be resolved to a type
    Destination cannot be resolved to a type
    MessageConsumer cannot be resolved to a type
    TextMessage cannot be resolved to a type
    ConnectionFactory cannot be resolved to a type
    Destination cannot be resolved to a type
    Session cannot be resolved to a variable
    Message cannot be resolved to a type
    TextMessage cannot be resolved to a type
    TextMessage cannot be resolved to a type
    JMSException cannot be resolved to a type
    JMSException cannot be resolved to a type

    at jmstestclient.SimpleSynchConsumer.main(SimpleSynchConsumer.java:51)
```

It points the error on import javax.jms line

Currently i donot have JEE or j2ee. I have only installed the jdk but not j2ee. DO i have to install the j2ee to connect the JMS server.

How can i be able to make this program compilable.

Answer (score 0):

Add the jar in the classpath of the application.

Comment: I am new to eclipse. How can i define my jar file in the classpath of the application

Comment: @Robinhood follow this http://www.wikihow.com/Add-JARs-to-Project-Build-Paths-in-Eclipse-%28Java%29

Comment: Thank you. I was able to build the jar file and the code has been compiled. Would you please suggest me how to run the above code to connect with JMS server. Do i have to install the j2EE and the above code will connect me to the JMS server.

Comment: @Robinhood if the suggestion work thn select as correct answer also you can find so many JMS server client example on google.follow one of this http://oreilly.com/catalog/javmesser/chapter/ch02.html If you find any pblm plz post your question.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am bit inexperienced on JMS. What are the basic requirement for working on JMS. I have installed JEE SDK. I have created a project as in above code. But i am confused regarding the JMS service. Do i have a JMS server. and how my queues are created. Do i have to create the queue on the JMS server or it can be created using the java code. In the above posted question, it returns System.out.println("Program takes one argument: <dest_name>"); output. How can i know my client is connected properly to the server.

Comment: @Robinhood First understand what is JMS,dnt move fast.Once you understand the process then search on google you will find so many example.We are having producer and consumer in JMS http://www.novell.com/documentation/extend52/Docs/help/MP/jms/tutorial/pointToPoint-1.htm One more link